# Why don't I get focusout() event, when an input field looses focus (using scrollbar)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iscroll

I'm trying to put an input field into a scrollbar using [iscroll5](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5). I need to listen to the input's focusout() event but I never get notified when clicking anywhere else.
It works when I remove the scrollbar!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

<title>iScroll demo: simple</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="iscroll5.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var myScroll;

function loaded () {
    myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', { mouseWheel: true });

   $("input").focusout(function(e) {
      console.log("input lost focus"); // NEVER GET HERE
   });

   $("input").click(function(e)  {
      console.log("input onClick");
   });
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="loaded()">
<div id="header">iScroll</div>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="scroller">
    <ul>
        <li>Pretty row 1</li>
        <li>Pretty row 2</li>
        <li>Pretty row 3</li>
        <li>Pretty row 4</li>
        <li><input type='text'></li>
        <li>Pretty row 6</li>
              ...............
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>

 <div id="footer"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure if this can help, but try using `blur` instead of `focusout`

Comment: It works when you click outside of the `#wrapper` div. However, when you click anywhere on the `#wrapper`, the input does not lose focus (that's why focusout is not triggered) because, somehow, the iScroll library prevents default behavior by handling the click/mousedown/mouseup events (to prevent default scroll). You can see that using the Tab key works. How to avoid this? That I don't know.

Comment: thanks, but blur doesn't work either. Is there a workaround I could do for this bug in iscroll?

Answer (score -2):

try to add 'preventDefault: false,' to the options, i have done and

Comment: A short answer is welcome, however it won't provide much value to the latter users who are trying to understand what's going on behind the problem. Please spare some time to explain what's the real issue to cause the problem and how to solve. Thank you ~